# JOOQ fetchLazy into POJO

Tags: java, jooq

So I'd like to fetch some records lazyly into POJOs using `DSLContext` like so:

```
public Iterator<Something> getSomething(DSLContext dsl) {
  return dsl.selectDistinct(STUFF.FIELD)
    .from(STUFF)
    .fetchLazyInto(Something.class)
    .iterator();
}
```

The problem is that there's no such `fetchLazyInto()` and I cant do something like `fetchLazy().into(Something.class)` neither

So how do I go about lazy fetching into a POJO? I'd rather avoid coding a `RecordMapper`

I certainly could do the following but it feels wrong:

```
dsl.selectDistinct(STUFF.FIELD)
   .from(STUFF)
   .fetchLazy()
   .stream()
   .map(Something::new) //now Something constructor is ugly
   .iterator();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using jOOQ API only as follows:

```java
dsl.selectDistinct(STUFF.FIELD)
   .from(STUFF)
   .fetchLazy()
   .stream()
   .map(r -> r.into(Something.class))
   .iterator();
```

However, do note that `Iterator` does not extend `AutoCloseable` and as such, you might have a dangling resource (the `Cursor`'s underlying JDBC `ResultSet`), which isn't closed as early as you stop processing the results. It will be closed only when you complete processing without errors, or when the `ResultSet` is garbage collected.